# Issues in converting array of list to numpy-nd array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a array of list which

**Input:**

```
array([list([1, 1, 1]),
       list([1, 1, 1])],dtype=object)
```

I want to convert it to numpy nd-array:

**Output:**

```
array([[1., 1., 1.,],
       [1., 1., 1.,]])
```

**I tried this code:**

```
import numpy as np
npa = np.asarray(someListOfLists, dtype=np.float32)
```

But if failed.

Comment: can you try `np.array`? Also, what input are you using to cast to numpy?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan, if `asarray` doesn't work, why would `array`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructing your array - simple copy-n-paste won't do it:

```
In [467]: a = np.array([None,None])
In [468]: a[:] = [1,2,3],[4,5,6]
In [469]: a
Out[469]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

YOur failed attempt, with **full traceback**:

```
In [471]: np.asarray(a, dtype=np.float32)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-471-a8170ed9d2a8>", line 1, in <module>
    np.asarray(a, dtype=np.float32)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

It's still trying to turn the 2 element object array into a 2 element float.

A working way:

```
In [472]: np.stack(a)
Out[472]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

another

```
In [473]: a.tolist()
Out[473]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
In [474]: np.array(a.tolist())
Out[474]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```